# Ruby For loop isn't running as expected

Tags: ruby, for-loop, methods, conditional-statements

I have this array of arrays:

```
WIN_COMBINATIONS = [
  [0,1,2],
  [3,4,5],
  [6,7,8],
  [0,3,6],
  [0,4,8],
  [6,4,2],
  [1,4,7],
  [2,5,8]
]
```

and I am defining this method:

```
def won?(board)
  for x in WIN_COMBINATIONS
    win_index_1 = x[0]
    win_index_2 = x[1]
    win_index_3 = x[2]
    p1 = board[win_index_1]
    p2 = board[win_index_2]
    p3 = board[win_index_3]

    if p1 == 'X' && p2 == 'X' && p3 == 'X'
      return x
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

and when

```
board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

The `won?` method returns every item in WIN_COMBINATIONS instead of false. I have no idea why and I would appreciate it if someone would please help.

Comment: You probably want `return false`

Comment: sadly no, now I get the error 'expected a collection that can be converted to an array with `#to_ary` or `#to_a`, but got false' instead of an overstuffed array. I'm passing tests made by an instructor

Comment: Can you show the tests that you are trying to make pass?

Comment: What should `won?` return if none of those `if` statements matches?

Comment: You are getting the result of the `for` block, in this case `WIN_COMBINATIONS`

Comment: describe "#won?" do
    it 'returns falsey for an empty board' do
      board = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]

      expect(won?(board)).to be_falsey
    end

Answer (score 3):

In `ruby` each `block`, returns something even if you don't explicitly return a value, in your case the `for block` is returning the collection over you are iterating I think that your logic is correct but you need to make a small change, something like:

```rb
def won?(board)
  for x in WIN_COMBINATIONS
    win_index_1 = x[0]
    win_index_2 = x[1]
    win_index_3 = x[2]
    p1 = board[win_index_1]
    p2 = board[win_index_2]
    p3 = board[win_index_3]

    return x if p1 == "X" && p2 == "X" && p3 == "X"
  end
  false
end
```

The code above will `return x` if any of the sequences are valid, false in any other case (although you should follow the convention and return `true or false` if you are using the signature `?`, other option is remove the `?` and return `nil` instead of false). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Every block of code returns a value even if there is no explicit `return` keyword. `for` loop returns itself. With `board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']` you never hit the `return x` statement and you get `WIN_COMBINATIONS` back.
If you replace `return false` with `return []`, it will allow you to avoid `'expected a collection that can be converted to an array with #to_ary or #to_a, but got false'`. But Ruby has [a bunch of nice methods to work with arrays](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html).

By convention, methods that end with `?` should return a boolean value. Your method returns an array when the `if` statement is true.
In your case, I'd rename the method and use the `find` method to iterate through `WIN_COMBINATIONS`:

```
def find_win_combination(board)
  # You can use decomposition as in the next example `do |wi_0, wi_1, wi_2|`
  win_combination = WIN_COMBINATIONS.find do |combination|
    win_index_0 = combination[0]
    win_index_1 = combination[1]
    win_index_2 = combination[2]
    # If it's true the find method will return the win combination
    board[win_index_0] == "X" && board[win_index_1] == "X" && board[win_index_2] == "X"
  end

  # return an empty array if win_combination is not found
  win_combination || []
end
```

```
board = [' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ']
> find_win_combination(board)
 => [3, 4, 5]

board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
> find_win_combination(board)
 => []
```

If you need `won?` method to return a boolean method, just use `any?` method on `WIN_COMBINATIONS`. The result of `any? will be returned as a result of` won`?

```
def won?(board)
  # Here is a decomposition of each item of `WIN_COMBINATIONS` into three variables
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.any? do |wi_0, wi_1, wi_2|
    board[wi_0] == "X" && board[wi_1] == "X" && board[wi_2] == "X"
  end
end
```

```
board = [' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ']
> won?(board)
 => true

board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
> won?(board)
 => false
```